# Hibernate Unknown entity at saving data to database

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am using Hibernate project in my eclipse with oracle database and java application.

after added new class(exist in my database) to my Hibernate project, and run my java project.it's loaded successfully also allow to add data from java project to hibernate table but at add these data to database i got this error

`Unknown entity: com.se.automation.db.client.mapping.DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS`

here is my code to add data to my database.

note ( I opened the session and i test it with another  class exist in the same Hibernate project with the same structure to this class "Hibernate Project" )

`DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS docstatus = new DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS();`

`docstatus.setOriginalDocId(doc.getPdf().getId());`

at this moment every thing fine , but below line give the error(test it in debugging mode)

`addDocumentWrongModDateStatus(docstatus ,Session );`

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>

    <!-- <property name="show_sql">true</property> -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
    <!-- auto commit -->
    <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0 -->
    <property name="c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">1000</property>
    <property name="c3p0.initialPoolSize">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxPoolSize">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxIdleTime">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxStatements">3</property>
    <property name="c3p0.minPoolSize">1</property>
<mapping resource="com/se/automation/db/client/mapping/DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/se/automation/db/client/mapping/DocumentCompareChangedFet.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/se/automation/db/client/mapping/DocumentCompareCode.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/se/automation/db/client/mapping/DocumentCompareComment.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/se/automation/db/client/mapping/DocumentCompareMethod.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
 <class name="com.se.automation.db.client.mapping.DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS" 
 table="DOCUMENTWRONGMODDATESTATUS">  

<id column="ID" length="33" name="id" type="long">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

   <property name="Status" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="STATUS" />
    </property>

    <property name="OriginalDocId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ORIGINALDOCID" />
    </property>

    <property name="RevDocId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="REVDOCID" />
    </property>

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS.java

```
 package com.se.automation.db.client.mapping;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class DocumentWRONGMODDATESTATUS implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private String Status;
private Long OriginalDocId;
private Long RevDocId;

public Long getOriginalDocId()
{
    return OriginalDocId;
}

public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStatus()
{
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status)
{
    Status = status;
}

public void setOriginalDocId(Long originalDocId)
{
    OriginalDocId = originalDocId;
}

public Long getRevDocId()
{
    return RevDocId;
}

public void setRevDocId(Long revDocId)
{
    RevDocId = revDocId;
}

{

}
}
```

Comment: Wow, `.hbm.xml` files - careful, that's an antique...

Comment: I found the problem, i was updated my Hibernate Tools in my eclipse and i forget that, and after go back to old version every thing work fine